# Probability Question - Random Variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose I have 300 daily returns that come from one of two distributions. The probability it comes from distribution 1 is 50% and the probability it comes from distribution 2 is 50% (i.e. equally weighted).

The first distribution is: X~N(0,0.01^2)
The second distribution is: Y~N(0,0.02^2)

What is the resulting distribution?

If both distributions are normal I believe it should be Z = 0.5X+0.5Y -> Z~N(0,0.000125)

Is this correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No it’s not correct

Comment: @Andrew thanks! Any direction you can point me in?

Comment: The resulting distribution is what you've written down in the second sentence; it's called a gaussian mixture in the literature. To correct it, you can write $Z = UX+(1-U)Y$ where $P(U=1)=P(U=0)=1/2$ and $U$ is independent of $X,Y$.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! That really helps :)

Comment: $Z$ does not have a normal distribution.  $Z$ has mean $0$ and variance $\frac{0.01^2+0.02^2}{2}=0.00025$